# Do all ESP32 pin can be used when using wifi?

Tags: esp32

lately I build a project which is use relay and several sensor, I also use wi-fi to connect it to internet, but when I try to code digital write use some pin, i tried pin 12, 13, 32, 25, it didn't work
when I tried it without connect it to wi-fi, it works
can someone help me please?

Comment: there could be a problem with analogRead but not with digitalWrite. didn't you forgot to call pinMode? https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html#adc-limitations

Comment: Hi rolandoartha, welcome to SO. Please post your code (as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), or we can't help you.